# Drop-in replacement for XMLHttpRequest to load local files

Tags: javascript, ajax

I’m getting `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied` when trying to load a webpage in the browser that was copied from the Internet.

I want the web page to run locally without a web server. So my question is whether there is any JavaScript library with a drop-in replacement for XMLHttpRequest that allows to do that.

Comment: Not sure how a different library will solve that. Better solve the underlying issue: See [“NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340482/ns-error-dom-bad-uri-access-to-restricted-uri-denied) and the questions linked to it, on our developers' sister site. For more, a little [Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q="NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI") gives tons of answers. Most likely a JS issue with the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: rraallvv: So you want the local HTML/JavaScript to be modified to point its XMLHttpRequest requests to a local dummy server, and this dummy server would send empty data, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul for instance a request to "sounds/music.mp3" should work either with a web page hosted in the local server (http://localhost/index.html) and also by loading index.html directly from the file system in the browser window (file:///path/to/index.html)

Comment: And would it try to load the mp3 file from the filesystem? Most XMLHttpRequest calls are for dynamic data, you can not know in advance what the request will ask for. Should the page saving mechanism try to imagine all things the XMLHttpRequest call can ever ask for?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think [createjs](http://www.createjs.com) does something like that but I have to dig deeper. They have the option `preferXHR` in the [LoadQueue](http://www.createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html) constructor for using HTML tags instead of XMLHTTPRequests